# Categorizing Medical Symptoms written in different ways using Python

Tags: python, nlp, modeling, data-manipulation

I have a set of medical records for which I need to categorize symptoms. The symptoms are written differently For eg: "Pain in Chest", "Chest Pain", "Discomfort in Chest" etc. Also there are some medical terms written for which I have to substitute by its meaning For eg: "C/O - Complains of", "SOB - Short of Breath" etc. How do i categorize these terms?

My larger aim is to build a probabilistic model which will help me identify if a patient has disease A and if he or she is prone to disease B based on historical data trends. Thanks in advance for the answer.

Comment: Take a look at Natural Language Toolkit http://www.nltk.org/

Comment: I did try NLP, What i am thinking of is generating Bigrams with the word "Chest" fixed and then take a count the resulting bigrams. I am not sure if its the right approach.

Comment: the challenge is to identify scientific medical terms which are not used in English language and then come up with a way to classify the symptoms.

Comment: You need to give more details about the historical data you have, for someone to give specific advice. Without knowing more about the problem, I think you'll definitely want to use NLTK for preprocessing (as previously suggested), and maybe scikit-learn for modelling.

Comment: Alternatively you might have some success with an LSTM neural network for natural language processing. I don't personally have any experience with it, but it seems like it might fit.